# parametrization of an espiral in polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, parametrization

I am trying to parametrize the following spiral in polar coordinates.
My book says

$$ \gamma  =  (t\cos t, t\sin t) ,\quad t \in [0,+\infty]$$

can be parametrized in polar coordinates as
$$\gamma_p  =  (t, t) , \quad t \in [0,+\infty]$$

But I am getting nowhere trying to prove that.
I am trying to do this as a way to understand the following:

> A curve in the plane can be defined by a continuous function
>
> $$\gamma_p: I \subseteq \mathbb R \to [0,\infty] \times \mathbb R$$ 
>   where 
>   $$\gamma_p=  (r(t), \theta(t))$$
>
> are the polar coordinates of a point in the image of the curve associated to the parameter $t$, which corrisponds to the curve
>   $$\gamma=  (r(t)\cos(\theta(t)), r(t)\sin(\theta(t)))$$
>   in cartesian coordinates.

which I am having trouble understanding because they are mixing polar coordinates, cartesian coordinates and  parametrization and I don't see  how polar coordinates can be seen as a curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is: given the point $(x, y) = (t \cos t, t \sin t)$ how do you represent it in polar coordinates? You just need to calculate the values for $(r, \theta)$, where

$$
r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt{(t\cos t)^2 + (t\sin t)^2} = t \\
\tan \theta = \frac{y}{x} = \frac{t \cos t}{t \sin t} = \tan t
$$

So you have that the representation of $(x, y) = (t \cos t, t \sin t)$ in polar coordinates is $(r, \theta) = (t, t)$. The spiral is just all the collection of all these points for $t \ge 0$

Comment: I had gotten the part $(x, y) = (t \cos t, t \sin t)$, just couldn't see how to write the (r,t) answer. What about the second part of the question? How do I understand polar coordinates as a curve, since they are coordinates

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver Each point along the curve has a coordinate, you could represent it in whatever system you want, it could be cartesian, polar, ... In this case, you're being as to calculate the polar representation of all points in a polar system given the cartesian representation